# Is using an object instantiation as an enum entry's value good practice?

Tags: java, object, enums, instantiation

First off, apologies if this is a duplicate of an existing question. Wasn't precisely sure how to word my question so that may be why I haven't found a clear answer yet. Essentially, I want to know if the following is considered good practice or if there is a better way to do this:

```
public enum ExampleEnum {
    ENTRY_1(new ExampleCodedValue("entry1", "comment1")),
    ENTRY_2(new ExampleCodedValue("entry2", "comment2")),
    ENTRY_3(new ExampleCodedValue("entry3", "comment3")),
    ENTRY_4(new ExampleCodedValue("entry4", "comment4"));

    private ExampleCodedValue codedValue;

    ExampleEnum(ExampleCodedValue codedValue) {
        this.codedValue = codedValue;
    }

    public ExampleCodedValue getCodedValue() {
        return codedValue;
    }
}

class ExampleCodedValue {

    private final String code;
    private final String comment;

    ExampleCodedValue(String code, String comment) {
        this.code = code;
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's a perfectly reasonable way to do it, however, couldn't you do this:

```
public enum ExampleEnum {
    ENTRY_1("entry1", "comment1");

    private final String entry;
    private final String comment;

    private ExampleEnum(String entry, String comment) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 KISS principle. BTW I commonly create enums with fields (like this). They can be remarkably handy.

Comment: The main reason is that this enum, and others like it, use a common datatype of `ExampleCodedValue`. So for instance you might have two enums, `Settings` and `Attributes`. Each consist of a code and a comment. It's an oversimplification of my actual use case but the two enums are distinct in terms of what they encapsulate. I also considered using @Jeffery's example and having an accessor method that returns the `ExampleCodedValue` type. Maybe that's a better way to do it?

Comment: @speedRS I was just wondering why you'd go to all the trouble to create an object that provided no extra functionality. But since your use case demands having that particular object, there is nothing wrong with your original example.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, since your `ExampleCodedValue` is immutable.

However, if it is just a value container, ask yourself if there is a good reason not to put the fields directly into the `enum`. A good reason might be that your value object is conceptually separate of other fields of the enums.

Another use case for objects contained in enums is to use polymorphism to give each of them different functionality. For example:

```
PAINT_BRUSH(new PaintTool()),
ERASER(new EraserTool());
```

With different implementations of `execute()` or so in `PaintTool` and `EraserTool`.

*At this point, you might ask yourself though, am I still using the `enum` to make a choice somewhere, or could I omit the `enum` altogether and just use the `Tool` instances directly... Also, traditionally, enumerations don't revolve around functionality.*

Answer (score -1):

Firstly why cant you simply add the code and comment properties to the enum itself ? It seems completely pointless.